# Why does my game in Epic Games Launcher shows Uninstall and I haven't installed it yet?

Tags: pc, killing-floor-2, epic-games-launcher

My Epic Games Launcher shows the game Killing Floor 2 with the "Uninstall" button, but I haven't installed it!
Is it because I stayed lots of time to forget the download?

Edit: I just logged in to play Fortnite after it logged me out somehow and it shows "Resume download". It sometimes shows me this and other times shows me that...
Any specific reason?

Comment: The first question is unclear. Do you mean, 'when I select killing floor 2 in the launcher there's an uninstall button', even though it has not been downloaded/installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer, to the second question would perhaps be: The launcher may be forcing an update of the multiplayer game in order to be able to play games on servers running the newer version.

When you log out of such a game, the launcher will have you download an update before letting you log in again. This is usually done to prevent problems where users forget/disable the update functionality and the game can lose some customers because they are running an eventually incompatible older build that cannot join in a newer game: instead of updating the higher barrier to entry may result in them doing something else instead.